# Does anyone have a fix for the Glassfish RAR5031 System Exception?

Tags: jdbc

I have posted this question over on Java.net twice in the past year and never recieved a solution.

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/managed-connection-not-valid-phyiscal-connection-not-usabl

If you google for RAR5031 you will find a page that basically says "Call Sun".

This error occurs after doing a JNDI lookup to get a JDBC DataSource, the exception is thrown on:

conn = dataSource.getConnection();

I have tried implementing a retry one time algorithm and this works sometimes.

This is on Glassfish 2.1.1 / Oracle 10g with the ojdbc6.jar file. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue on GlassFish 4.0.1-b05 using Java DB 10.10.1.3.